# node.js and socket.io application not running

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a small application which doesn't seem to work. Please help.

Server:

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(9002);


io.enable('browser client minification'); 
io.enable('browser client etag');   
io.enable('browser client gzip'); 
io.set('transports', [         
    'websocket'
  , 'flashsocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
]);



console.log("listening on port 9002");


app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.emit('serverevent',{ name: 'server' });
    socket.on('firstevent',function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log("one client disconnected");
    });
});
```

Client

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket=io.connect('http://localhost:9002');
    socket.on('serverevent', function(data){    
    console.log(data);
    alert(data);
    socket.emit('firstevent', { name: 'manu mehrotra' });
    });
$(function(){
    socket.emit('firstevent', { name: 'manu mehrotra' });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Nothing is printed in server log or console on connection and nothing is returned back by the server to the client to be shown in an alert box.

I am running this stuff on amazon ec2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is because you're listening for localhost on your client.